# Xml to equivalent dynamic xml set from class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_weather9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Πίσω" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/weather1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But in my application I want inside my class, to set a new xml dynamically with the same things as above. I do no know what exactly will be the parameters. So far I have written this. Can you help me with it and complete what is missing:

```
final LinearLayout test2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        test2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        test2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        final Button Back = new Button(this);
        Back.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Back.setText("Back");

        test2.addView(Back);

        final LoaderImageView image = new LoaderImageView(this, ImageUrl);
        image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I am more interested in ScaleType because the `image.ScaleType(FILL)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what do you want to achieve. A java code that construct exactly the same layout as the XML? If so why? Or, are do you want to modify at run time some aspect of the XML layout, if so what aspect?

Possibly there are simpler ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: yes exactly this. a java code that constructs the same layout. This is because I have added a loader in my app before any image loads from a url, and so far I can only make this work only with setting dynamically the xml. And because its only for one xml i consider easier make the java code to give me the same layout that I want, as having a static xml.